# Lombok, Jacksonized; How to create custom class objects when constructing core class from json

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I have three classes, first: "ItemProduct" has, among other properties, two fields that are class-based. Class "Reservation" and class "Something". "ItemProduct" and "Reservation" are model classes based on json response from API. Class "Something" is generated using data from ItemProduct and Reservation and is used later for other operations.

Code:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class ItemProduct {
    @NotNull
    Integer id;
    @NotNull
    String status;
    @NotNull
    String productType;
    String productNo;
    @NotNull
    Reservation reservation;
    @JsonIgnore
    Something something;

}

@Data
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class Reservation {
    @NotNull
    Integer reservationLine;
    String reservationDescription;
}

@Data
@Jacksonized
@Builder
public class Something{
    @NotNull
    Integer reservationLineNo;
    @NotNull
    String reservationType;
    String serialNumber;

    public static final List<Something> stuff = new ArrayList<>();

    public Something(@NotNull Integer reservationLineNo, @NotNull String reservationType) {
        this.reservationLineNo = reservationLineNo;
        this.reservationType = reservationType;
        something.add(this);
    }

    public Something(@NotNull Integer reservationLineNo, @NotNull String reservationType, String serialNumber) {
        this.reservationLineNo = reservationLineNo;
        this.reservationType = reservationType;
        this.serialNumber = serialNumber;
        something.add(this);
    }
```

I create objects of class ItemProduct as follow:

```
ItemProduct itemProduct = objectMapper.readValue(input_real, ItemProduct.class);
```

Input:

```
{
"id": 4011821,
"reservation": {
    "reservationLine": "3",
    "reservationDescription": "xxx"
},
"status": "PROCESSING",
"productType": "TOOL"
}
```

Problem:
How can I, during construction of objects ItemProduct, construct objects of class Something? With code mentioned above I don't create objects of class Something. I would like to make a call: Something(this.reservation.reservationLine, this.productType) in ItemProduct class constructor.

I tried tinkering with writing my own Contractor for class ItemProduct, but it only partialy worked - got NPE from using Builder annotation during deserialisation. Also, it generated a lot of additional boilerplate code (there will be more optional class properties in ItemProduct).

---

Edit:

Dirty "solution" is adding constructor to ItemProduct:

```
    ItemProduct(@NotNull Integer id, @NotNull String status, @NotNull String productType, String productNo, @NotNull Reservation reservation, Something something){
    this.id = id;
    this.status = status;
    this.productType = productType;
    this.reservation = reservation;
    this.productNo = productNo;
    this.something = new Something(reservation.reservationLine, productType);
}
```

So, please correct me, I need to make constructor that uses all possible properties? Do I need to make other constructor variants including unused "Something something" arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before pointing you to a technical solution, let me first explain why I think your design is flawed.

In general, you should design your classes with the "separation of concerns" principle in mind. The main concern of your `ItemProduct` and `Reservation` classes is deserialization. However, the concern of `Something` seems to be something completely different, although it's unclear what that is (storing some state of the reservation? holding internal data?).

My advice is to separate these concerns also in your code. You can achieve this in several ways. One way could be to map the input classes to a different set of classes; you can do that manually or with helper tools like [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/).

If you still want a technical solution, you can implement an all-args constructor for `ItemProduct` manually. Jackson will construct the instance using `ItemProductBuilder.build()`, and that calls this constructor. So if you want to populate `something`, that's a way to do that.

Another solution is to create a manual getter for `something` and create the instance in there lazily upon the first call to that method.

PS: You should aim for immutable classes. So if possible, use `@Value` instead of `@Data`. If you have a builder, you also don't need more than a (private) all-args constructor, because you would always use the builder to create instances.

Comment: Thank you! I don't have controll over ItemProduct (or: API response in JSON form that describes what ItemProduct is). Class "Something" is used as proxy object that I can work on, add logic, etc... In the end objects of class "Something" are used to create request body for different API call.

Thank you for pointing out:
* MapStruct - will look into it,
* Immutability of classes

Comment: Yes, what you describe really screams "map me to internal value classes". You then will have full control over these and can add your logic without thinking about Jackson etc.